# Build a sleek NAS- Attached Ubuntu-Based filing Kiosk

Tags: python, html, ubuntu, nas, kiosk

I want a Kiosk-esque Machine to accept various media including SD-, XQD-, CF-Cards and USB drives and prompt the user with a selection of fields to enter various data in such as date, internal ID and comments and then based on the media-type and entered data to copy the contents onto a QNAP NAS System.

It should also check for duplicate data and prohibit potential doubles from the copying.

I have tried to get [this](https://obrienlabs.net/setup-kiosk-ubuntu-chromium/) going with 20.04 LTE on an older "left-over" office machine and seems to kind of work, but I'll work out the kinks myself.

My plan was to locally host an HTML/CSS site and handle the small backend bit with python.

Is that a viable and effective plan or is there an option I'm not seeing?

Comment: [Flask](https://github.com/pallets/flask) might be what you need. You can run the site locally, and handle the backend with python. It should be fairly easy to implement.

Comment: Its also pretty easy to set up chrome in Kiosk mode: https://www.appsadmins.com/blog/chrome-kiosk-mode-introduction